# Relationship between file properties and user and group

Tags: files, group

There is something not clear on relationship between file properties  and user and group.

```
root@debian:/home/debian# ls  -l  /home/linuxsir
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 linuxsir root 1549 Feb 23 19:16 test.txt
```

I draw a conclusion that the directory /home/linuxisir contain one file 
named test.txt, linuxsir is its owner ,and linuxsir belong to the root group.

```
root@debian:/home/debian# cat /etc/group
root:x:0:
linuxsir:x:1004:
postgres:x:120:
my_test_group1:x:1005:linuxsir,linuxsir2
```

From cat /etc/group , linuxsir do not belong to group root?
How to  think of this matter properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `cat /etc/group` only shows the groups created in the system. If you want to know which groups `linuxsir` belongs to, you need to use this command `groups linuxsir`.

The result of `ls -l`says:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 linuxsir root 1549 Feb 23 19:16 test.txt
```

It means:

- user linuxsir is *owner* and can read and write on test.txt
- group root can only read
- Anyone else can only read

It doesn't say that `group root`is owner of the file, it is only saying which permissions `group root`has over the file.

By default, the *owner* of a file is the user who *created* it and the *group* assigned to a file is the *primary group* of the user. However, you can change the group of a file  using `chgrp`.

Comment: In my situation, groups linuxsir
linuxsir : linuxsir my_test_group1

Comment: The User `linuxsir` only belongs to the groups `linuxsir` and `my_test_group1`. He isn't on the group `root`.